# Tab delimited saved file missing tab for empty cell

Tags: excel, vba, tabs, export, csv

I am writing code in excel vba to convert data and save as a tab delimited txt file.  All fields export ok but if there is no data in the a column it does not insert a tab in the saved file

```
  'Exporting Sheet as Tab Delimited Text File To Target Path
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=SavePath & WS.Name, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
```

This is the code to export / save file.

The source data is as laid out as follows in columns

```
A     B     C     D     E
```

With data in B and C - I would like resulting file to be formatted as

```
TAB   B/TAB   C/TAB   TAB   TAB
```

I have tried to write a character in to the relevant cell to no avail with the following - as it just inserts 2 x tabs

```
Cells(t, 1) = Chr(11)
```

Where loop on T for number of rows

Comment: I have no problems with your code, the `tab` are present. Does you columns D and E contains text somewhere (Headers maybe?). If the columns contains no data anywhere, they won't be exported.

Comment: There is Tab only if there is a used column after.

Comment: Could use a picture of input / output here and also ideally your entire procedure / function code.

Comment: I need resulting txt file to have 5 tab data fields.  If the column in the column on the spreadsheet does not contain data I need to export the tab only.  if this makes sense.  I can get the file to write but with columns ABCDE if ADE have not data it only exports with tabs CD.

Comment: @I.Bailey -  Are you looking for a CSV (Comma Delimited File) or a *Tab-delimited-file*?  If you actually need to generate a tab-delim file, the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50858597/8112776) will still work, just replace the two occurences of `','` with `vbTab`.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure will create a CSV file, including blank columns, in the range from A1 to the bottom-right of the `UsedRange`:

```
Sub makeCSV()
    Const outFile = "C:\yourpath\output.csv"
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rgExport As Range, c As Variant, v As String, strOut As String

    'figure out range: from A1 to bottom-right of 'UsedRange'
    Set rgExport = ws.Range("$A$1:" & Split(ws.UsedRange.Address, ":")(1))

    'parse range
    For Each c In rgExport
        'if the cell contains a comma put quotes around it
        If InStr(c, ",") <> 0 Then v = """" & c & """" Else v = c
        'add cell to output string
        If c.Column = rgExport.Columns.Count Then
            'last column in range: add CR+LF
            strOut = strOut & v & vbCrLf
        Else
            'not last column: add a comma
            strOut = strOut & v & ","
        End If
    Next c

    'create text file (will overwrite if it already exists)
    Open outFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, strOut
    Close #1

    Debug.Print "Exported " & rgExport.Address & " to " & outFile
    MsgBox "Exported " & rgExport.Address & " to " & outFile

End Sub
```

Change the output file name and source sheet name at the top of the procedure.

---

Alternatively, you can change the procedure to export from varying *input sheets* to varying *output files* by replacing the first **three** lines with these **two** lines:

```
Sub makeCSV(sheetName as String, outFile as String)
    Set ws = Sheets(sheetName)
```

...and then calling it like:

```
makeCSV "Sheet1", "c:\yourPath\output.csv"
```